# What is according Java data type for JPA mapping for PostgreSQL's Time with time zone?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JDK 15 and Java 15, Spring Boot version `2.3.4.RELEASE`, FreeMarker, PostgreSQL 13.

What is according Java data type for JPA mapping for PostgreSQL's Time with time zone?

File `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/freemarker
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

# create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Hibernate properties
# https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL95Dialect.html
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql =true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates
spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftlh
```

database

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.inventory_item
(
    id integer,
    inventory_item_name character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
    manufactor_id integer,
    created time with time zone,
    modified time with time zone,
    user_created integer,
    user_modified integer,
    inventory_item_type_id integer,
    original_price numeric(222),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE public.inventory_item
    OWNER to postgres;
```

This entity mapping cause error at `created` and `modified`

```java
package com.example.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_item", schema = "public", catalog = "freemarker")
public class InventoryItem {

    private Integer id;
    private String inventoryItemName;
    private Integer manufactorId;
    private Date created;
    private Date modified;
    private Integer userCreated;
    private Integer userModified;
    private Integer inventoryItemTypeId;
    private BigInteger originalPrice;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "inventory_item_name")
    public String getInventoryItemName() {
        return inventoryItemName;
    }

    public void setInventoryItemName(String inventoryItemName) {
        this.inventoryItemName = inventoryItemName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "manufactor_id")
    public Integer getManufactorId() {
        return manufactorId;
    }

    public void setManufactorId(Integer manufactorId) {
        this.manufactorId = manufactorId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "created")
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "modified")
    public Date getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_created")
    public Integer getUserCreated() {
        return userCreated;
    }

    public void setUserCreated(Integer userCreated) {
        this.userCreated = userCreated;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_modified")
    public Integer getUserModified() {
        return userModified;
    }

    public void setUserModified(Integer userModified) {
        this.userModified = userModified;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "inventory_item_type_id")
    public Integer getInventoryItemTypeId() {
        return inventoryItemTypeId;
    }

    public void setInventoryItemTypeId(Integer inventoryItemTypeId) {
        this.inventoryItemTypeId = inventoryItemTypeId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "original_price")
    public BigInteger getOriginalPrice() {
        return originalPrice;
    }

    public void setOriginalPrice(BigInteger originalPrice) {
        this.originalPrice = originalPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        InventoryItem that = (InventoryItem) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(inventoryItemName, that.inventoryItemName) &&
                Objects.equals(manufactorId, that.manufactorId) &&
                Objects.equals(created, that.created) &&
                Objects.equals(modified, that.modified) &&
                Objects.equals(userCreated, that.userCreated) &&
                Objects.equals(userModified, that.userModified) &&
                Objects.equals(inventoryItemTypeId, that.inventoryItemTypeId) &&
                Objects.equals(originalPrice, that.originalPrice);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, inventoryItemName, manufactorId, created, modified, userCreated, userModified, inventoryItemTypeId, originalPrice);
    }
}
```

[image]

I know the problem cause by the mapping (exactly)

```sql
    created time with time zone,
    modified time with time zone,
```

and

```java
    private Date created;
    private Date modified;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why would you store a create/modify value as a "time" (hour, minute, second) without "date" (year, month, day)? What good is it to know that the item was last modified at 3:14 PM if you don't know how many days ago that was? Did you perhaps mean to use `timestamp with time zone`, not `time with time zone`?

Comment: we use offsetDatetime in java with postgres version 11 and it works well.

Comment: @Vignesh_A Using `OffsetDateTime` works well for a column that doesn't store *date* (year, month, day), only *time* (hour, minute, second) and *zone offset*? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: @Andreas I actually meant whatever you said is working for me as well. its stores with date,year,month and with time . OffsetDateTime is right data type to be used along with jpa for postgres.

Comment: @Vignesh_A Offset**DateTime** is *not* the right data type for a column that only stores "**time** of day (**no date**)" *(quoted [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html))*.

Comment: [Don't use timetz](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz) - you should really be using `timestamp with time zone`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the PostgreSQL documentation, section [8.5. Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html), `time with time zone` stores:

> time of day (**no date**), with time zone.

In Java, the best match is [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html):

> A time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as `10:15:30+01:00`.
>
> `OffsetTime` is an immutable date-time object that represents a time, often viewed as hour-minute-second-offset. This class stores all time fields, to a precision of nanoseconds, as well as a zone offset. For example, the value `"13:45.30.123456789+02:00"` can be stored in an `OffsetTime`.

However, be aware that the PostgreSQL documentation says:

> We **do not recommend** using the type `time with time zone` (though it is supported by PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL standard).

Answer (score 0):

Try ZonedDateTime

```
private Integer id;
private String inventoryItemName;
private Integer manufactorId;
private ZonedDateTime created;
private ZonedDateTime modified;
private Integer userCreated;
private Integer userModified;
private Integer inventoryItemTypeId;
private BigInteger originalPrice;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "inventory_item_name")
public String getInventoryItemName() {
    return inventoryItemName;
}

public void setInventoryItemName(String inventoryItemName) {
    this.inventoryItemName = inventoryItemName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "manufactor_id")
public Integer getManufactorId() {
    return manufactorId;
}

public void setManufactorId(Integer manufactorId) {
    this.manufactorId = manufactorId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "created")
public ZonedDateTime getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(ZonedDateTime created) {
    this.created = created;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "modified")
public ZonedDateTime getModified() {
    return modified;
}
```

Comment: According to the PostgreSQL documentation, section [8.5. Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html), `time with time zone` stores *"time of day (**no date**), with time zone"*, so `ZonedDateTime` is definitely not correct.